# React-Router Links component declaration

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to make a simple wizard for in React and trying to use react-router from Rackt.

I have issues with importing external components to the routing defintion

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { Router, Route, Link } from 'react-router'
import Wizard from './Wizard/Wizard.js'

class Wizard1 extends React.Component  {
  render() {
    return (
      <div><Link to="/step2">#2 lol</Link></div>
    );
  }
}

class Wizard2 extends React.Component  {
  render() {
    return (
      <div><Link to="/step3">#3</Link></div>
    );
  }
}

class Wizard3 extends React.Component  {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>Wizard3</div>
    );
  }
}

render((
  <Router>
    <Route path="/" component={Wizard}>
      <Route path="step1" component={Wizard1}/>
      <Route path="step2" component={Wizard2}/>
      <Route path="step3" component={Wizard3}/>
    </Route>

  </Router>
), document.getElementById('root'))
```

And the external component `Wizard` is defined like this

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router'

export class Wizard extends React.Component  {

  render() {
    return (
      <Link to="/step1">START</Link>
    );
  }
}
```

And the START link doesn't render, manually navigating to the steps works fine. Guidance would be much appreciated. There are no errors in the console and the app runs fine except the aforementioned issue.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are importing like:

```js
import Wizard from './Wizard/Wizard.js'
```

You need to export like:

```js
export default class Wizard
```

It's not really anything to do with React or React Router; that's just how ES6 modules work.

Answer (score 2):

As per es6 syntax there are 2 types of export defined for a module.

1. **Default** export done as `export default Wizard;` It can be imported easily by doing import Wizard from './Wizard/Wizard';
2. **Named** export which can be done as `export const sqrt = Math.sqrt;` and used as import { square } from 'lib';

Also, in your `react-router` configuration you have defined nested routes. Wizard1, Wizard2, Wizard3 will be rendered inside **Wizard** component. You should write Wizard.js like

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router';

export default class Wizard extends React.Component  {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <Link to="/step1">START</Link>
      {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```